# Failed to get Route detail between two locations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Map control (using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps) in windows phone 8.1 App.

For Getting route deail i am working as per following link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631250.aspx

I have created Map service ApplicationID and Map service AuthenticationToken as described in following link and set it in my app.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741528.aspx

While debugging, controls goes on following line but never give any result.

```
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(loGeoPoint1, loGeoPoint2, MapRouteOptimization.Time, MapRouteRestrictions.None);
```

I have checked i am passing valid geopoints. and also have set valid Map service token and application ID.

Can anybody tell me, What i am missing?

Comment: Maybe you need a capability in the app manifest?

Answer (score 0):

There is not mistake in "MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync" function.
I was finding by setting current location at place where no way present. I tried by setting current location on highway and it is working fine now.

thank you.